# Add Custom Control as Marker OSMDROID BONUS PACK

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

Can I add Custom Control as Marker to OSMBONUSPACK?

I create some Buttons and image in Android xml file Named MyMarkerItem.xml

I would like something like `MyMarker.setDesign(R.layout.MyMarkerItem);`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I understand that you want the marker icon itself to be not a simple bitmap, but a layout.

What you can do is to use the marker infowindow "instead" of the marker icon.

First of all, create a new class CustomInfoWindow which inherits from MarkerInfoWindow - the default InfoWindow for Markers, and uses your own layout:

```
public class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {
    public CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
        super(my_own_layout, mapView);
    }
}

CustomInfoWindow myCustomInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindow(mapView);
```

Then, just after creating your Marker, do that:

- Set a marker icon as a 1x1 pixel size bitmap, fully transparent: setIcon(mySmall_InvisibleIcon)
- Set the marker infowindow to your own: setInfoWindow(myCustomInfoWindow)
- Set the infowindow "anchor" to the most appropriate and natural position, depending on the "look" of your layout: setInfoWindowAnchor(ANCHOR_CENTER, ANCHOR_CENTER) maybe?
- Force the opening of the infowindow: showInfoWindow()

All these steps are fairly simple.

But then, I guess you expect some behaviour to happen when the user will click on your layout buttons. 
So, inside your CustomInfoWindow code, you will certainly have to do some work => follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2#7-customizing-the-bubble-behaviour).

Comment: I tested it, that's great and simple to code. I have just a problem, when I change the marker position, it while duplication (no with a new instance)  but the draw it duplicated. For a marker A when i moved it with it windowsInfo, I will have A moved and A' in the first place. Any action like button click on A' handle the marker A. Is it normal ? Thanks

Comment: Not obvious to understand... Could you rephrase correctly? Also, ensure you create and set a new customInfoWindow for each marker (don't share the same infowindow between markers).

Answer (score 1):

Markers in Osmdroid arent actually android views and therefore it's not possible to add other components into them. They are basically just an image.

**Simple and suggested solution**

You can add your components to a [MarkerInfoWindow](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/infowindow/MarkerInfoWindow.html) which is displayed after a click, though.

```
marker.setInfoWindow(new MarkerInfoWindow(R.layout.MyMarkerItem, mapView));
```

**Possible "real" soluiton**

If you really need such behaviour - meaning you really need multiple buttons displayed on a map as a "marker" and give the user the opportunity to click on them - it should be possible to create your own implementation of a Marker-like class. In other words, you would have to implement your own subclass of [OverlayWithIW](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/OverlayWithIW.java) or [Overlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Overlay.java) and override (mainly) the `draw` method (which should draw your buttons to a canvas) and the `onSingleTapConfirmed` method, where you would need to detect properly on which button user clicked and call the related action. Try to go through [source of the Marker class](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Marker.java), it's a good example.

But keep in mind: this is an advanced task. Everything related to drawing on canvas can lead to performance issues if it's not done properly. There will be edge cases you'll have to cover. There may be other problems you'll need to solve and debug. I would not suggest such a solution to a beginner.

Comment: So, there are no way to add multiple button in the same marker, using it as overlay for exemple ?

Comment: Do you suggest any other API ?

Comment: @nadjibnet Well, you cannot do this with `Marker`. If you really need such behaviour it would be possible to implement your custom Marker-like class. I'll extend my response to add some hints towards that.

Comment: Yes please, For example: I need to make multiple button around a icon

Comment: @nadjibnet Sorry, but what you want to achieve is very unclear for me. Do you want to customize the InfoWindow of a Marker (which is easy to do)? Or have a layout instead of the Marker itself? Please provide an example, I'm sure we will be able to help.

Comment: @MKer I want to have an advanced marker. To put as example a multiple button in a marker (Not in InfoWindow). I want to set the design of the marker using XML layout. I tried to override a draw, as said in the answer, nothing happened (I called "myView.draw(canvas)"). I steel working on it...

Comment: When I try the **Simple and suggested solution**, `marker.setInfoWindow(new MarkerInfoWindow(R.layout.MyMarkerItem, mapView));` I get a runtime exception when I click it: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`. My layout contains a TextView widget only.

Comment: @John You should follow the stack trace of the exception since it tells you your layout is not conforming to the expectations the component has. Apparently you need to have at least 2 TextViews with `R.id.title` and `R.id.description` as ids. At least that seems to be the case based on the code. https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/infowindow/BasicInfoWindow.java

Comment: There was no stack trace. I drew my own conclusions and wrote another answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's August 2021 and I wanted to add an arbitrary layout as my marker item. Much as the OP is asking for here.

I tried the **Simple and suggested solution** of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53003664/866333:

`marker.setInfoWindow(new MarkerInfoWindow(R.layout.MyMarkerItem, mapView));`

I get a runtime exception when I click it:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`.

I refine my layout down to a single TextView widget for arguments sake and the error persists.

---

I give up on that answer and attempt the accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53216542/866333

```
public class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {
    public CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
        super(my_own_layout, mapView);
    }
}

CustomInfoWindow myCustomInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindow(mapView);
```

Using the same `my_own_layout` as before, let's call it `R.layout.my_info_window`

I get the same error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

I dug into the AS-reverse engineered (thanks AS) source code to discover the reason for this error is that the layout being passed to the `MarkerInfoWindow` super class constructor has particular id requirements.

We must have these ids in our layout: `bubble_title`, `bubble_description`, `bubble_subdescription`, `bubble_image`

Here is a minimal working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble_subdescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bubble_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/marker_cluster"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="145dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="76dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

That works great!

I can even *attempt* to customise by appending another widget:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anothertexttestview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="look ma!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="125dp" />
```

The `absoluteY` is ignored and superimposed on the only text I set programmatically, the title. IOW, the widget isn't purely declarative xml. I'm afraid `ConstraintLayout` is after my time as a front end engineer so I'll leave it to the reader to experiment from here.