# Adding button to marker information on OSMDroid

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have this few lines of code:

```
Marker mPin = new Marker(map);
mPin.setPosition(new GeoPoint(peak.cordX, peak.cordY));
mPin.setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_default));
mPin.setTitle(peak.Name);

// There I want to add button

String cX = Double.toString(peak.cordX);
String cY = Double.toString(peak.cordY);
String cZ = Double.toString(peak.cordZ);

mPin.setSubDescription("Cords: " + cX + ", " + cY +
  "\nHigh: " + cZ);

map.getOverlays().add(mPin);
```

and I would like to add into Marker mPin button which is clickable. 
Are there any possibilities to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to display a button instead of an icon, and what happen when users click on that button? Is there any different between icon and button when users click on them?

Comment: I want to put a button inside icon information because there should be an option "AddStartPeak" and "AddEndPeak" for creating a Path between two (or more) points. It's typical for some map applications.

Comment: I think you can use `setInfoWindow()`, when users click on the icon, the info window will pop up with two options ("AddStartPeak", "AddEndPeak"). Because info window allows you use custom layouts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Custom Control as Marker OSMDROID BONUS PACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999592/add-custom-control-as-marker-osmdroid-bonus-pack)

Comment: This is an idea I wanted to get. I will handle this and inform you if it works.